# respond_with and namespaced controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make use of rails 3's respond_to/respond_with mechanism for restful controllers. I'm finding that when I try and use those features within a namespaced controller the redirects fail and i have to specify the optional location: parameter on the respond_with.

So right now I have:

```
def Admin::FooController
  respond_to :html, :xml
  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
    @foo.save
    respond_with(@foo, location: admin_foo_path(@foo))
  end
end
```

If I don't provide the location parameter it attempts to redirect to just foo_path(@foo)

Any ideas as to why this would be / if I'm doing something wrong or does rails 3's default responder just not handle namespaced URL routes?

Answer (score 17):

respond_with(:admin, @foo)

This [blog](http://blog.stoutdesign.com/2010/11/rails-3-respond_with-restful-resources-and-namespaces/) has more..